# PySpark: Filling missing values in multiple columns of one data frame with values of another data frame

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have one data frame (D1) as follows:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 
22   | null | 23   |  56
12   |  54  | 22   |  36
48   | null | null |  45
null | 32   | 13   |  6
23   | null | 43   |  8
67   | 54   | 56   |  null
null | 32   | 32   |  6
3    | 54   | 64   |  8
67   | 4    | 23   |  null
```

The other data frame (D2):

```
col_name  |  value
col 1     |  15
col 2     |  26
col 3     |  38
col 4     |  41
```

I want to replace the null values in each column of D1 with the values from D2 corresponding to each columns.

So the expected output would be:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 
22   | 26   | 23   |  56
12   |  54  | 22   |  36
48   | 26   | 38   |  45
15   | 32   | 13   |  6
23   | 26   | 43   |  8
67   | 54   | 56   |  41
15   | 32   | 32   |  6
3    | 54   | 64   |  8
67   | 4    | 23   |  41
```

I would like to know how to achieve this in PySpark data frames.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach, but since we are using [`crossJoin`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.crossJoin), it may not be the most efficient, but since the `D2` is relatively small, it should be ok. Other way could be `udf`.

```
# Creating the DataFrame
values = [(22,None,23,56),(12,54,22,36),(48,None,None,45),
(None,32,13,6),(23,None,43,8),(67,54,56,None),
(None,32,32,6),(3,54,64,8),(67,4,23,None)]
D1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(values,['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
D1.show()
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|  22|null|  23|  56|
|  12|  54|  22|  36|
|  48|null|null|  45|
|null|  32|  13|   6|
|  23|null|  43|   8|
|  67|  54|  56|null|
|null|  32|  32|   6|
|   3|  54|  64|   8|
|  67|   4|  23|null|
+----+----+----+----+
```

We need the list of columns to iterate upon, so the code below gives that.

```
list_columns = D1.columns
print(list_columns)
    ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
```

Creating the second DataFrame.

```
D2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('col1',15),('col2',26),('col3',38),('col4',41)],['col_name','value'])
D2.show()
+--------+-----+
|col_name|value|
+--------+-----+
|    col1|   15|
|    col2|   26|
|    col3|   38|
|    col4|   41|
+--------+-----+
```

Let's [`pivot`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot) the DataFrame D2, so that we can append it along all columns.

```
#Pivoting and then renaming the column
D2_new = D2.groupBy().pivot('col_name').sum('value')
D2_new = D2_new.select(*[col(c).alias(c+'_x') for c in D2_new.columns])
D2_new.show()
+------+------+------+------+
|col1_x|col2_x|col3_x|col4_x|
+------+------+------+------+
|    15|    26|    38|    41|
+------+------+------+------+
```

Finally using crossJoin, we append them -

```
# Appending the columns
D1 = D1.crossJoin(D2_new)
D1.show()
+----+----+----+----+------+------+------+------+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col1_x|col2_x|col3_x|col4_x|
+----+----+----+----+------+------+------+------+
|  22|null|  23|  56|    15|    26|    38|    41|
|  12|  54|  22|  36|    15|    26|    38|    41|
|  48|null|null|  45|    15|    26|    38|    41|
|null|  32|  13|   6|    15|    26|    38|    41|
|  23|null|  43|   8|    15|    26|    38|    41|
|  67|  54|  56|null|    15|    26|    38|    41|
|null|  32|  32|   6|    15|    26|    38|    41|
|   3|  54|  64|   8|    15|    26|    38|    41|
|  67|   4|  23|null|    15|    26|    38|    41|
+----+----+----+----+------+------+------+------+
```

Once this main `DataFrame` is obtained, we can just use simple [`when-otherwise`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) construct to do the replacement by running a loop over the list of columns.

```
# Finally doing the replacement.
for c in list_columns:
    D1 = D1.withColumn(c,when(col(c).isNull(),col(c+'_x')).otherwise(col(c))).drop(col(c+'_x'))
D1.show()
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|  22|  26|  23|  56|
|  12|  54|  22|  36|
|  48|  26|  38|  45|
|  15|  32|  13|   6|
|  23|  26|  43|   8|
|  67|  54|  56|  41|
|  15|  32|  32|   6|
|   3|  54|  64|   8|
|  67|   4|  23|  41|
+----+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can create a `column_name:value` mapping and then just do `fillna()` on each column:

```
mapping = { row.col_name.replace(' ',''):row.value for row in D2.collect() }
#{u'col1': 15.0, u'col2': 26.0, u'col3': 38.0, u'col4': 41.0}

# fillna on col1 for testing
D1.fillna(mapping['col1'], subset=['col1']).show()
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|22.0| NaN|23.0|56.0|
|12.0|54.0|22.0|36.0|
|48.0| NaN| NaN|45.0|
|15.0|32.0|13.0| 6.0|
|23.0| NaN|43.0| 8.0|
|67.0|54.0|56.0| NaN|
|15.0|32.0|32.0| 6.0|
| 3.0|54.0|64.0| 8.0|
|67.0| 4.0|23.0| NaN|
+----+----+----+----+

# use a reduce function to handle all columns
df_new =  reduce(lambda d,c: d.fillna(mapping[c], subset=[c]), D1.columns, D1)
```

Or use list comprehension

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import isnan, when, col

df_new = D1.select([ when(isnan(c), mapping[c]).otherwise(col(c)).alias(c) for c in D1.columns ])
```

**Note:** for StringType columns, replace the above `isnan()` with `isnull()`

Comment: question along the same lines as this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62276949/pyspark-filling-nulls-upon-condition @jxc

Comment: in this particular example, isNotNull() doesn't seem to work, how come?